# Web Project Templates Missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've installed the VS Community 2015 Update 1 but I'm not able to see the Web Project templates. I have done everything, reinstall, repair, reinstall the templates using devenv /installvstemplates, remove the ProjectTemplatesCache folder, pretty much everything I've found about similar issues but without results.

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only thing that actually solved this issue: uninstall every single component manually installed (I assume that restoring the system to a previous point should work as well)...